# Calc function with percentage and pixel. Cross browser issues

Tags: css

I've got a simple social media sidebar that sticks to the left side of the browser, half way down the screen always (so it follows when scrolling). It is working perfectly in Internet explorer, but I'm getting issues in Chrome and Firefox. In Chrome, the bar appears correctly 50% down the screen, but it doesn't move when scrolling. In Firefox, the bar is located at the top left (wrong position) and also does not move when scrolling.

I did some investigating and found out that the calc function can vary from browser to browser. I've added what I think is the necessary CSS for all browsers, but still no luck.

[IE Visual (working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPdf7.png)

[Firefox Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sscXW.png)

[Chrome Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KBHb.png)

```
.fbIcon {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;

  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  /* Firefox */
  top: -moz-calc(50% - 128px);
  /* WebKit */
  top: -webkit-calc(50% - 128px);
  /* Opera */
  top: -o-calc(50% - 128px);
  /* Standard */
  top: calc(50% - 128px);

  background-image: url('icons/64/fbIcon.png'); }

 .linkedIcon {


background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  /* Standard */
  top: calc(50% - 64px);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  /* Firefox */
  top: -moz-calc(50% - 64px);
  /* WebKit */
  top: -webkit-calc(50% - 64px);
  /* Opera */
  top: -o-calc(50% - 64px);

  background-image: url('icons/64/linkedIcon.png'); }
```

etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot help you with the cross browser issues without seeing the actual site, but you can solve this task without calc(). Position the bar 50% top and assign a negative margin that is half of the height of your bar. Also you should not position each icon separately, but the bar itself.

In your case it should be something like that:

```
.icons_bar {
  width: 64px;
  height: 128px;

  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -64px;
}
```

Here is a working example: http://codepen.io/matuzo/pen/MYbqZG